# Return results of ID NOT IN Certain Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a write and the logic I am looking for is basically. If any User IDs from Table 1 do not exist in Table 2 show those in the results. So I did:

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  UserColder.Phone,
  UserColder.Email,
  UserColder.Website,
  Country.Name,
  UserColderZIP.[ZIP Code],
  UserColderZIP.[State Abbreviation]
FROM
  dbo.UserColder
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON UserColder.ID = CountryUser.[User ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.Country
    ON CountryUser.[Foreign ID] = Country.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserColderZIP
    ON UserColder.ID = UserColderZIP.UserColder
WHERE
  UserColder.ID NOT IN (CountryUser.[User ID])
```

It returns data without the `Where` But with the `Where` I am trying to get it to show all the results where the Id from UserColder don't have any records in CountryUser. Right now it is returning no results and I know ID 2 doesn't exist in there. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, to get records from `UserColder` that don't exist in `CountryUser`, check for `NULL`.  The joined rows which have no corresponding value will return `NULL`.

```
WHERE
  CountryUser.[User ID] IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense but it returns no records for the missing one. Is it possible to make it show which one is missing?

Comment: @Justin Based on what you have above, I would expect it to work correctly. Debug by removing the columns and joins to `dbo.Country` and `dbo.UserColderZIP` to reduce it only to `UserColder` and `CountryUser`

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the information from UserColder and make sure that the `UserColder.ID` is not in `CountryUser` by checking it (select statement in where).

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  UserColder.Phone,
  UserColder.Email,
  UserColder.Website,
  Country.Name,
  UserColderZIP.[ZIP Code],
  UserColderZIP.[State Abbreviation]
FROM
  dbo.UserColder
  INNER JOIN dbo.Country
    ON CountryUser.[Foreign ID] = Country.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserColderZIP
    ON UserColder.ID = UserColderZIP.UserColder
WHERE
  UserColder.ID NOT EXISTS (select [user id] from dbo.CountryUser where CountryUser.[User ID])
```

Comment: not exists is better option, to avoid query failing on null user id values

Comment: Thanks! That's what I am trying to do. I tried this but it returns no records for the missing one. Is it possible to make it show which one is missing?